# Adding border around ripple effect button in android?

Tags: android, button, layout, view

I have used the following code to add ripple effect to my button, but the border around it has disappeared and the button has merged with the back ground. I want to add border around it to distinguish it.

This is the code of my button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/action_sign_in" />
```

This is the drawable for the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1dp"
        android:radius="0.1dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="1dp"
        android:topRightRadius="1dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#E8E6E7" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually have both by using `background` and `foreground` properties, like so:

```
android:background="@drawable/the_name_of_your_button_file"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

is causing the button to take on the theme, and blend into the background as if transparent.  You are not pointing to the drawable file for the button, which has the stroke element, which gives the border.

If you want a border, you must use the stroke element in your drawable by pointing to it with:

```
android:background="@drawable/the_name_of_your_button_file"
```